# How do i replace space in environment variable (batch)

Tags: variables, batch-file, setx

I am using this code to create an environment variable with the current date and time:

```
setx timestamp "%DATE:/=-%@%TIME::=-%"
```

The effect of using this command is to create a string value "timestamp" in HKCU\Environment with the data value "Fri 26-04-2013@18-32-31.29".

What i want is to remove that space from "FRI" and "26-04-2013@18-32-31.29" to make it 
"Fri-26-04-2013@18-32-31.29".

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 set timestamp="%DATE:/=-%@%TIME::=-%"
 set timestamp=%timestamp: =-%
 setx timestamp %timestamp% /K HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ENVIRONMENT
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set timestamp=%timestamp: =-%
```

should set all spaces currently in 'timestamp' to dashes